# $\lim\limits_{A \to \infty} (1 - \frac{c}{A})^{N-1}$, $N \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda A)$

Tags: probability, statistics, self-learning, poisson-distribution

Given $N \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda A)$, what will be $(1 - \frac{c}{A})^{N-1}$, where $c$ is a constant, when $A \to \infty$?

Will it converge into a distribution or a constant? And what is it?

---

Here is a try:

From @zhoraster, $N$ is distributed as $P_1 + \dots + P_A$, where $P_k$ are iid $\mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$.

By the law of large numbers, $\frac{N}{A} \to \lambda$, $n\to\infty$, in probability.

$$
(1 - \frac{c}{A})^{N-1} 
= \left((1 - \frac{c}{A})^{\frac{A}{c}} \right)^\frac{c(N-1)}{A} 
= \exp\left(\frac{c(N-1)}{A} \log\left((1 - \frac{c}{A})^{\frac{A}{c}} \right)\right)
$$

Since we have 
$\lim_\limits{A \to \infty} (1 - \frac{c}{A})^{\frac{A}{c}} = e^{-1}$
and $\frac{N}{A} \to \lambda$ as $A \to \infty$. We can obtain
$$\lim_{A \to \infty}\frac{c(N-1)}{A} = \lambda c$$
And 
$$
\lim_{A \to \infty} \log\left((1 - \frac{c}{A})^{\frac{A}{c}} \right) = -1
$$
Thus, 
$$
\lim_{A \to \infty} \left(\frac{c(N-1)}{A} \log\left((1 - \frac{c}{A})^{\frac{A}{c}}\right)\right)  = -\lambda c
$$
$$
\lim_{A \to \infty}(1 - \frac{c}{A})^{N-1} = e^{-\lambda c}
$$

**However, I am not sure if steps are rigorous enough** because $A$ can be any positive real number but not necessary a positive integer. Any correction and suggestion is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: It not only will, it does. Did you try to prove this yourself?

Comment: @zhoraster It should convert into a constant, I think the result $\lim\limits_{A \to \infty} (1-\frac{1}{n})^n = e^{-1}$ is useful, but I just don't know how to handle the power $N-1$ and express it in term of $A$

Comment: Can you prove the convergence of N/A?

Comment: The appears to be almost the same thing as [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rao%E2%80%93Blackwell_theorem#Example).  That might tell you what to expect the limit to be. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $N$ is distributed as $P_1 + \dots + P_A$, where $P_k$ are iid $\mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$. So by the law of large numbers, $N/A \to \lambda$, $n\to\infty$, in probability.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-clicked it. Just one more question, is my proof is rigorous enough?

Comment: @kitman0804, yes, perfect!